# Convert string to list of strings

Tags: python, eval, python-re

this is my string:

```
s = '[111,222],333'
```

I want to convert it to tuple (or list) of 2 items (list +string), but **don't want to convert the string to int**!
By using eval / ast.literal_eval I'm getting a tuple with ints.
My wanted output is:

```
(['111','222'],'333')
```

Comment: Well, you could use a regex to replace `(\d+)` with `"\1"` before calling `literal_eval()`, but that's going to fail if you are ever given a string that has already-quoted numbers in it.

Comment: A strange requirement, in my mind, but I would use the re module to put quotes around all digit sequences, then proceed as you have been.

Comment: Any sane deserialization function would look at that string and see integers. So you will need to be explicit and write a deserialization function that casts the values back to strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this:

```
def convert_rec(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return list(map(convert_rec, x))
    else:
        return str(x)

s = '[111,222],333'
s = eval(s)
res = convert_rec(s)
print(type(res[0][0]))
```

the output if this print is:

```
<class 'str'>
```